# What is the need of consumer group in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I don't understand the practical use case of the consumer group in Kafka.
A partition can only be read by only one consumer in a consumer group, so only a subset of a topic record is read by one consumer.

Can someone help with any practical scenario where the consumer group helps?

Comment: What happens when a consumer restarts? What offset will be used? Have you researched how "offset commits" are maintained?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think whenever consumer reads it maintains a log of it and next time when consumer starts reading again it will check that log and take offset from there.

Comment: Correct... But consumer groups make that possible. Specifically, restarting a consumer of the same group, rather than a new id

Answer (score 3):

It's for parallel processing of event messages from the specific topic.

> Consumers label themselves with a consumer group name, and each record published to a topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each subscribing consumer group. Consumer instances can be in separate processes or on separate machines.

> If all the consumer instances have **the same consumer group**, then the records will effectively be **load balanced** over the consumer instances.

> If all the consumer instances have **different consumer groups**, then each record will be **broadcast** to all the consumer processes.

Read more here:

- https://docs.confluent.io/5.3.3/kafka/introduction.html#consumers

Comment: Groups are also used to track comitted offsets

Comment: can I declare how many consumers I need in a group through code?
because right now where I work there is no mention of the number of consumers we want in a group. we just declare the groupId and that's it.

Comment: In spring-kafka there's a concurrency setting... Confluent maintains a "parallel consumer" external repo... Otherwise, you can create an ExecutorPool of threads, but the better option is to deploy multiple instances of your app, for example in auto scaling group or Kubernetes